# Why is this binding not working?

Tags: wpf, xaml, object, binding, text

I have a textbox inside a style, whose text property is bound to the name property of my object here is the code:

```
<Style TargetType="s:Node">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <TextBox x:Name="textboxName" Text="{Binding Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag, Mode=TwoWay}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/> 
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Inside the constructor for node I have:

```
public Node()
    {
        Name = "node";
        Tag = 100;    
    }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That code won't compile, there can be no direct content in a style...

Comment: @H.B. i removed some code, when posting, I added the template tag, that should compile I think.

Comment: It won't, you need a `Setter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Source` does not process a `RelativeSource` the way the `Binding` does when set as `Binding.RelativeSource` but just takes that markup extension object and looks for properties on it.

A `RelativeSource` ***describes*** how a relative source should be found and should hence not be used *directly* as the `Source` for a binding.

Comment: H.B. I think I understand what you are saying, but I am not sure how to write it, what should the correct binding be?

Comment: @mihajlv: Didn't you already figure that out in your own answer? (Also the TargetType of the template should be the same as the TargetType of the style)

Comment: I thought I did, but it only bounds to the tag property, when I try to bound to the Name property it gives me the ToString() method, this is what I am using:
`<TextBox x:Name="textboxName" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>`
-----------------
`<TextBox x:Name="count" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag,Mode=TwoWay}"/>`

Comment: @mihajlv: That sounds weird, are you overriding an existing name property or something like that? Does this cause binding warnings or errors?

Comment: No, I put the name change in Loaded, and it worked, I know, it is weird how it works for the Tag property but not for Name. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Source should be RelativeSource, I am not sure why it doesn't work this way.